# How to multiply measures across dimension in Power BI tables?

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, business-intelligence, powerquery

I have a complete report in Excel and now I'm trying to replicate it in Power BI. Now I have some issues regarding calculation. Since it's not possible to use cell references in PBI and the concept is completely different, I keep having problems with it.

Examples of how the value is calculated in Excel using dollar signs and cell references. **I would like to do the same multiplying process in Power BI that is done in Excel in the following screenshots.** What is important to point out is that the values in the Excel tables are already calculated measures.

Picture 1: 
[image]

Picture 2: 
[image]

Picture 3: 
[image]

Picture 4:
[image]

Screenshot of the upper table in Power BI, which values I would like to use to calculate the same thing.

[image]

I've tried to use Power BI quick measures to resolve this issue, but unfortunately it didn't help me. Did some research as well, but didn't find a similar issue, so that's why I created a new post.

Here's some sample data to test this thing (the same data from the Excel screenshots)

```
    RollRate                
    Bucket  31.05.2019  30.04.2019  31.03.2019  28.02.2019
    0   33% 30% 30% 30%
    1   66% 69% 69% 72%
    31  90% 87% 88% 85%
    61  88% 91% 95% 93%
    66  100%    100%    100%    100%
    PD              
    Bucket  31.05.2019  30.04.2019  31.03.2019  28.02.2019
    0   17% 17% 17% 17%
    1   52% 55% 57% 57%
    31  79% 79% 83% 79%
    61  88% 91% 95% 93%
```

Maybe anyone could help me with this issue. If anything is confusing, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the "Product" function in DAX
PRODUCT
12/09/2018
2 minutes to read

Returns the product of the numbers in a column.

To return the product of an expression evaluated for each row in a table, use PRODUCTX function (DAX).

Syntax
DAX

Copy
PRODUCT()
Parameters